# Derivatives of $g(x)=2 \cdot [4-f(5x)]^{-1}$: not sure how to apply chain and multiplication rules

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The function can also be written as $g(x)=2 \cdot [(4-x)^{-1} \circ f(5x)]$, so the first derivative is $$\begin{align} &g '(x)=2 \cdot [[(4-x)^{-1}]' \circ f(5x)] \cdot [f(5x)]' \\
& g'(x)=(-2) \cdot [4-f(5x)]^{-2} \cdot 5f'(5x) \end{align}$$ What I am having trouble with is the second derivative; I think I should treat it as $$\begin{align}
& g''(x)= (-2) \cdot [[4-f(5x)]^{-2} \cdot 5f'(5x)]'\\
& g''(x)= (-2) \cdot [[4-f(5x)]^{-2}]' \cdot [5f'(5x)] + [4-f(5x)]^{-2} \cdot 5[f'(5x)]']\end{align}$$
but I'm not fully certain so I'd like a bit of advice.

Comment: Because it's $(4-x)^{-1}$ composed with $f(5x)$ and multiplied by a constant.

Comment: I don't follow...

Comment: @graydad Read the formula again, I never wrote $2 \cdot [4 \circ f(5x)]^{-1}$.

Comment: Whoops, I did make a typo. But I still disagree with the equality. I wrote an answer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in the derivative of $g(x) =2 \cdot [4-f(5x)]^{-1}$ then let $h(x) = 4-f(5x)$. This should make the derivative of $g$ pretty easy. $$g'(x) =\left[2 \cdot [h(x)]^{-1}\right]' \\ = (-1) \cdot 2[h(x)]^{-2} \cdot h'(x) \\ = -2\frac{h'(x)}{\left(h(x)\right)^2}$$ Now we can plug in $h(x)$ and $h'(x) = -5f'(5x)$ to get a final answer of $$g'(x) = \frac{(-2) \cdot (-5f'(5x))}{(4-f(5x))^2} \\ = \frac{10f'(5x)}{(4-f(5x))^2} $$

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense to consider $g(x)=2 \cdot [(x)^{-1} \circ [4-f(5x)]]$ considering negative exponents are a way of expressing a quotient, I should have realised that sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Simple application of the chain rule:
$$
g^{\prime}\left(x\right)=\frac{10f^{\prime}\left(5x\right)}{\left(f\left(5x\right)-4\right)^{2}}
$$
and
$$
g^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)=\frac{50\left[\left(4-f\left(5x\right)\right)f^{\prime\prime}\left(5x\right)+2f^{\prime}\left(5x\right)^{2}\right]}{\left(f\left(5x\right)-4\right)^{3}}.
$$